# Find maximum of a square wave with variable frequency

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, measurement

I have an experimental signal (measure) that looks like a pwm signal:
[image: signal of interest]

I want to find the x coordinate (time) of the maximum, i.e., the x coordinate where there is more density of the high values (255) of the signal. By high density of 255 values, I mean a higher proportion of 'on' time. For instance, by visual inspection I can determine that this coordinate will be between 600 and 1100 (range marked in red), since the measured value in this range stays at 255 longer time than outside this range.

Any ideas on how can I get this coordinate?

Comment: Yes there is an easy way to do this, what is your tool of choice? (MATLAB, Octave or Python SciPy.signal)?

Comment: My tool of choice is python SciPy.signal, numpy, opencv, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and robust solution would be to low pass filter with a post-processed "Zero-phase" filter, the result of this will be time aligned with the input waveform and provide an averaged value over an observation interval.

The OP mentioned Python tools as a preference, and this is done simply with `scipy.signal.filtfilt` for coefficients that can be designed using `scipy.signal.firls` or simply a moving average over $N$ samples by using all ones for the coefficients. `filtfilt` will process the signal over the filter twice, so the result if a simply moving average is done would actually be equivalent to a triangular weighted average.

Ultimately I recommend considering the bandwidth of the signal modulating the PWM, and design a least squares filter (using `firls`) sufficient to pass this bandwidth and then rejection reasonably beyond that. As mentioned above, the processing with `filtfilt` will pass the signal through this filter twice (in the forward and reverse direction, hence cancelling out the linear phase and resulting in a time aligned "zero-phase" result).

Another approach is to just subtract out the delay of a standard linear-phase FIR filter since the delay for a linear-phase FIR with $N$ coefficients is simply $(N-1)/2$ samples, but I find using `filtfilt` simple and straightforward for this purpose.

Below is a simple demonstration of this using a 30 sample moving average:

```
smooth = sig.filtfilt(np.ones(30),30, pwm)
```

[image: result]